Why I get this error in PyScripter? "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"
I'm trying to run play.py from this project on github https://github.com/geohot/twitchchess. But I get this error on PyScripter
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 94, in main
    t = SimpleServer(ModSlaveService, port = port, auto_register = False)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\utils\server.py", line 89, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
Exit code:  1Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\PyScripter\remserver.py", line 94, in main
    t = SimpleServer(ModSlaveService, port = port, auto_register = False)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\utils\server.py", line 89, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
Exit code:  1

